# Duplicate class found in file, Data Binding, Room DB

Tags: android, database, android-room, android-databinding

I am facing a very annoying error. I am implementing room DB. When i write insert Query for another table in DAO, class android studio generate a compilation error related to android data binding
here is my DAO Class

```
@Dao
public interface MyCustomDAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertShop(ShopModel shop);

    //whenever i write this insert query, my android studio generate the stated error
   // and when i remove it project buil successfully

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertAbout(AboutEntity about);

    @Query("Select * From shops")
    LiveData<List<ShopModel>> getShopsData();

}
```

here is my About Entity Class

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "about",
    foreignKeys = {@ForeignKey(entity = ShopModel.class,parentColumns = "shop_id",childColumns = "id")}
    )
// i have implemented the shopModel class with a col namely, shop_id
public class AboutEntity {

@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
private String shopId;
@ColumnInfo
private String monToFriTiming;
@ColumnInfo
private String satTiming;
@ColumnInfo
private String sunTiming;
@ColumnInfo
private String description;

public AboutEntity(@NonNull String shopId, String monToFriTiming, String satTiming, String sunTiming, String description) {
    this.shopId = shopId;
    this.monToFriTiming = monToFriTiming;
    this.satTiming = satTiming;
    this.sunTiming = sunTiming;
    this.description = description;
}

@NonNull
public String getShopId() {
    return shopId;
}
// other fields getter Methods
```

}

Here is the ShopModel class

```
@Entity
public class ShopModel {
@NonNull
@PrimaryKey
@ColumnInfo(name = "shop_id")
private String id;

 // some other fields and their implementation in the constructor and getter methods for them

public ShopModel(@NonNull String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@NonNull
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

}
[build failed log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nnKzW4tytnuXv6kd6_YK8qOkWOcS4BWM)

Comment: Could you please provide the errors you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell without seeing the actual errors you are getting, but my guess is that your issue is due to having multiple insertion methods for different entities in the same DAO.

Instead of doing this:

```java
@Dao
public interface WrongDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertShop(ShopModel shop);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertAbout(AboutEntity about);

    @Query("Select * From shops")
    LiveData<List<ShopModel>> getShopsData();
}
```

In general, you should always **create a different DAO for each entity** to keep your code more organised:

```java
@Dao
public interface ShopDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertShop(ShopModel shop);

    @Query("Select * From shops")
    LiveData<List<ShopModel>> getShopsData();
}
```

```java
@Dao
public interface AboutDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertAbout(AboutEntity about);
}
```

I am not sure whether this is mandatory in Room, but so far all examples I have seen have one DAO per entity, so I would probably stick to that.

From the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Dao.html):

> It is recommended to have multiple Dao classes in your codebase
>   depending on the tables they touch.

To get this working properly, remember to include all your DAOs in the declaration of your Room database!

Comment: why is it necessary to use different dao for every entity?

Comment: To be fair, I don't think that having a single DAO is necessarily a bad thing in all cases, specially if you only have three or four queries in total. However, every Room implementation I have seen did use one DAO per entity. As I said, it is hard to know what you problem is if you don't share the error logs. Have you tried my solution to see if my implementation works for you?

Comment: no i did not yet because i dont know the prons and crons of your solution

Comment: i read at android documentation, the single dao can be use but it leads to a messy code, different DAOs code is easy to readable. i realy dont know why is it showing error with databinding approach

Comment: I think it is a matter of clarity and separation of concerns. A single DAO can easily grow and get very messy, while having one per entity will always be clearer and more organised. Besides, having different DAOs can help reducing boilerplate code via inheritance (for example, you could have a base class like `BaseDAO<TEntity>` with common CRUD operations already implemented).

Comment: That log doesn't say much, but there is probably some error message with useful information that you could share here. Have you tried moving the problematic insertion method to a different DAO as I suggested?

Comment: that useful error just say compilation error nothin else

Comment: But you said you error was related to data-binding, yet there is nothing about data-binding in the logs you have shared...

Comment: With only this information available, all I can think of is that one DAO having insertion methods for different entities. Have you tried implementing my solution to see if the error goes away?

Comment: the title of the question is related to the databinding error

Comment: In your question, you literally state that Android Studio shows an error related to data-binding, but there is no mention of data-binding in the build logs you have shared. How do you even know that the error is related to data-binding?

Comment: On the other hand, I have asked you several times if you had tried my implementation. Could you please tell me if my proposed solution solves your problem or not?

Comment: i dig into the problem. and your solution is right.Every entity should have the different data access object (DAO).

Comment: Glad to hear it! :)